# Payoff matrix of a scenario and the Schelling point.

Tags: game-theory, artificial-intelligence

Consider the problem of two people trying to drive safely on a two lane road. Each player can drive on their right or left. If players follow the same convention, they’ll drive safely. If they do not, they’ll crash into each other. Write a payoff matrix that describes this scenario and does this problem have a Schelling point?

I came up with the following payoff matrix. Is it correct?

```
                **Player 1**

                            Left        Right
**Player 2**    Left        Crash       Safe 
                Right       Safe        Crash
```

I'm thinking they are both safe if they drive in separate lanes.

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_point_(game_theory)#Real-Life_application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_point_(game_theory)#Real-Life_application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it exactly backwards. Players 1 and 2 are facing each other. So Player 1's Left lane is Player 2's Right lane. If Player 1 chooses left while Player 2 chooses right, they will end up in the same lane and crash. That is why the problem states "If players follow the same convention" (i.e., both drive on the left, or both drive on the right) "they'll drive safely".